# WPF Textbox "normal" text input

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-controls

G'day,

I'm not sure if this is a problem relevant to only me or if anyone else has this issue also. None the less, I'll try and describe what is going on here.

I have a few textbox's, default style, etc. I set an explicit maxwidth and maxheight to prevent resize when the text exceeds the default width of the textbox. The issue is that the text wraps to the next line, but I only want single line. So I set maxlines to 1 and textwrapping to NoWrap. That's fine.

Now the carat and typed text disappears under the edges of the textbox when the width is exceeded and the only way I can get the carat and newly typed text back into view is by pressing the left and right arrows. Coming from MFC and using textboxes all the time with HTML, I would have thought the default behaviour would be to have the textbox content scroll with the carat or am I missing something here?

Thank you,

Ash

Comment: Could you please post your exact code because for me it always works as expected.

Comment: to make sure there is no style set, you can explicitly set it to null: style="{x:null}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are requesting is actually the default behavior.  Start with an empty grid and place a textbox on it. Type some text into the box and the text view will scroll with the caret.

Below is the XAML I tested with, perhaps you have a style interfering with it?

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox MaxWidth="20" Height="20"></TextBox>
 </Grid>
```

Comment: Yes you are right, something is interfering with it. Created a new project and worked as it should. Crap, I don't know where to start looking for this problem haha.

Comment: It is a large project Too large to post XAML. I'll create a backup of the project and disable the surrounding styles one by one first to isolate the troublesome style :) Then I will post back.

Comment: Found the problem. You were correct Greg. There was a ScrollViewer style which wasn't being used, but was in my resource dictionary. Once I removed it, all textbox's worked as they should. Thank you very much.